# JMSTemplate and recipient list

Tags: spring, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I've read the documentation and I've seen a similiar question (from late 2005) but it seems no one got an answer. ( http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/9152-jmstemplate-oracle-jms )

I'm trying to send a message to a Topic using JmsTemplate while specifying the subscriber but either I'm not able to find the correct documentation or I can't find the correct API.

Is it possible to achieve something like this with JmsTemplate?

If you need any additional information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMSTemplate high-level methods only support the JMS Standard.

This is an extension to JMS...

> Adds Oracle Streams Advanced Queuing specific extensions to javax.jms.TopicPublisher

Sometimes you can handle such extensions with `JmsTemplate.execute` with a session callback but I think, in this case, you need to create a specific type of session. So, I think you are stuck with rolling your own code.

You could subclass `JmsTemplate` and override `createSession` to create the right kind of session; then you can use...

```
    Boolean result = template.execute(new SessionCallback<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean doInJms(Session session) throws JMSException {
            Topic topic = ((AQjmsSession) session).getTopic(...);
            ((AQjmsTopicPublisher) publisher).publish(topic, topicSession.createTextMessage(message),recipientL ist1);
            return true;
        }
    });
```